# In url routing named parameters are not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, url-routing

I have a about us page url like below:

```
base_url/cmsPages/index/cmsid:1
```

And in routes.php i have defined

```
Router::connect(
        '/about_us',
        array('controller' => 'cmsPages', 'action' => 'index', 'cmsid' => 1), 
    );
```

But i am not getting `cmsid` in `$this->request->params['named']['cmsid']` at `index action`.

Please help, how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following:

```
public function index($cmsid = null) {
    // some code here...
}

// routes.php

Router::connect(
    '/about_us',
    array('controller' => 'cmsPages', 'action' => 'index'),
    array('pass'=>array('cmsid'=>1))
);
```

for detailed information please visit following link :

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action

Comment: Thanks, I have done the coding part and all links are also set, is it not possible to pass to pass `cmsid` as named parameter.

Comment: Please have a look on this url : 
http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Configuration.html#named-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for getting named parameter

```
Router::connectNamed(array('id'));
    Router::connect('/about-us:id', array(
        'plugin' => false
        'controller' => 'cmsPages', 
        'action' => 'index'
        ),array(
            "pass"=>array("id")
        ),array(
            'id' => '[0-9]+'
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using named parameters, you can define this route

```
Router::connect(
    '/about_us',
    array('controller' => 'cmsPages', 'action' => 'index'),
    array('cmsid'=>1)
);
```